# What is the policy or best practice on posting the same question to multiple StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion

I originally posted a question to Network Engineering and was informed that the community was only for professional engineering and that my question on open source was misplaced. They suggested Super User.

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50302/how-do-i-make-ppp-reliable-over-lossy-radio-modems-using-open-source-pppd-on-deb

So I posted the question on Super User but through subsequent research found that the Unix Linux community would be more likely to engage an answer so I have now posted it there too.

Is this ok?

Answer (score 5):

From [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/267099):

> NO
>
> Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. If, like in this case, it does not get any answer, ask a moderator to migrate the question, or alternatively, delete it and re-ask it.

If you really want to ask on multiple sites, then your question must be tailored as necessary to make it site specific.

Having said that, if editing would make your question sufficiently different on each site, then it is probably too broad in the first place.